# OpenCV cvLoadImage() does not load images in visual studio debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to work out a simple hello world for OpenCV but am running out of ideas as to why it is not working.

When I compile and run this code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h> 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "myjpeg.jpg" );
 cvNamedWindow( "MyJPG", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 cvShowImage("MyJPG", img);
 cvWaitKey(0);
 cvReleaseImage( &img );
 cvDestroyWindow( "MyJPG" );
 return 0;
}
```

I get a grey box about 200x200 instead of the indicated .jpg file.  If I use a different jpg I get the same kind of window, and if I put an invalid filename in, I get a very tiny window (expected).

I am using Visual Studio 2008 under Windows 7 Professional.

Most of the sample programs seem to work fine, so I am doubly confused how that code loads the sample jpgs just fine but in the code above it does not work (even tried the sample jpeg).

### Update

The executables produced by compiling work fine, however the Visual Studio 2008 debugger loads a null pointer into img every time I try to run the debugger - regardless if the file location is implicit or explicit.

Comment: On what platform does you compile the program?
Can you check if the image is actually loaded 

if(img == NULL)
{
std::cout << "Trouble" << std::endl;
}

Comment: More testing shows the executable works fine outside the visual studio environment provided the OpenCV .dll files are present in the same directory, but indeed, img is a null pointer after cvLoadImage() is called when running in the debug environment.

Comment: The problem might be that your program is not executed in the same directory as the image file resides in. (this is a problem as you use a relative path)

Comment: This seems to be a problem related the debugger.  I replaced the relative path with an explicit one and still the img variable comes back a null pointer after cvLoadImage(), but the executable runs correctly (image is displayed) when run standalone (with appropriate files local).

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: OpenCV2.0 is the version being used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really seems like there's a problem with the path to `myjpeg.jpg` since the current directory could be different when you're running under the debugger.

By default, the current directory that the Visual Studio debugger uses is the directory containing the `.vcproj` file, but you can change it in the project properties (Debugging -> Working Directory).

Are you 100% sure that you pass the absolute path correctly? Try to pass the same path to `fopen` and see if it also returns `NULL`. If so, then the path is incorrect.

If you want to see exactly what file is the library trying to open you can use [Project Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with a filter on `myjpeg.jpg`.

Comment: That did the job.  The .jpg was in the debug directory with the executable instead of in the project directory with the vcproj file.  I don't know why the explicit path declaration would not work, I would guess there is always the possibility I did not pass the explicit path correctly.  Thanks very much everyone!

Comment: @Catalin_lacob 
I need your help. I tried what you said. fopen does not return NULL, neither does cvLoadImage, bt cvShowImage shows a greybox......

Comment: never mind, found it, since I did not have waitkey and cvrelease afterwards it did not work, do not know why though

Answer (score 1):

Which version of OpenCV are you using? I've tried your code on the latest (OpenCV2.0) and it works fine. You can download OpenCV2.0 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).

If you want the latest build, you can get check it out with SVN from [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv).

Comment: If so you should consider using the `Mat` class and the `imread` function - the new C++ interface is **much** better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `HAVE_JPEG` into preprocessor definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The Debug version does not load the image, but when I compile and link it as a Release it works. I hope this helps